# Subclassing EDIT control

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm subclassing an edit control, and I'm looking for a message I could intercept that would allow me to capitalize the first letter in the box.
`WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_CHAR` don't seem to have anything that identifies the characters case.

I currently have this working semi-good by processing the `EN_UPDATE` message in the parent window, but since I'm already subclassing the edit control, I'd prefer to do it in the subclassed proc.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Using one of the notifications (`EN_CHANGE`) is really the way to go. If you used a sane windowing framework that reflected notifications from parent back to the originating control then you would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, WM_CHAR definitely gives you case.  WM_KEYDOWN doesn't.  It doesn't solve your problem however, you also need to deal with WM_PASTE.  Using EN_UPDATE is fine, it is sent in both cases, just watch out for recursion.  And the pita of the parent getting it, the kind of problem that any class library solves.